# ArrayFormula() with SumIf() Matching "This" Row()

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to achieve the following functionality: 
In every row look at the value of column `B` (for example) 1. Then run down the list summing the value of column `C` if the value of column `B` is also (for example) 1 and capture this in each rows column `G`.

So the expected result for rows 4,5 and 6's `G` would be 3,3 and 1 respectively.

[image]

I am thinking something like (this is pseudo)

```
=ArrayFormula(SumIf(RangeForB,THISROW=OTHERROWS,RangeForC))
```

I'm also not really sure how I would get "This Row", I know you can use `ROW()` but that will give me the index not the value of the row. `INDEX()` to my knowledge also isn't usable in `ArrayFormula()`

Help would be greatly appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: how did you get 3,3??

Comment: Row 4, B cell is a 1, take the 1 from C cell. Row 5, B cell is a 1, take the 2 from C cell. No more rows with B cell 1. Sum 1+2 =3. So row 4 G cell is 3. Same for Row 5. There are two rows with B cell 1, there C cells are 1 and 2. Sum 1+2=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMIF where the criterion is itself a range:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(sumif(C4:C,C4:C,D4:D),C4:C<>""))
```

So the sumif is evaluated first for all of the rows where the values in column C match the number in C4 (rows 4 and 5), then for those matching the number in C5 (also rows 4 & 5), then those matching the number in C6 (row 6 only). The filter is needed to suppress the zeroes which would otherwise occur in rows 7 onwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(QUERY(B1:C, 
 "select B, C where B matches '1' and C matches '2'", 0),
 (TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:C1)^0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, I need it to be a little more dynamic however.